# My images expanded inside the grid when i added overflow: hidden to their container

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

I just finished adding a transform to the images inside my grid so they display a little zoom when hovering over them. I then added a overflow: hidden to the class ".post" where the images are contained so they dont zoom out of the grid.
However, as soon as i add the overflow hidden, my images expanded a little and i can't fix it. Only by removing the overflow hidden.

Below is my html and css code and 2 photos: one of before adding the overflow hidden (which is how i want the final product to look like) and one of the aftermath.

[BEFORE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcZx9.jpg)

[AFTER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVzId.jpg)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="post box1">
    <img src="images/favfilms.jpg" alt="">
    <p class="img-text">Ranked: My Favorite Movies (5★ ratings)</p>
    </div>

  <div class="post box2">
    <img src="images/chungking.jpg" alt="">
    <p class="img-text">Chungking Express Review</p>
  </div>

  <div class="post box3">
    <img src="images/donnie.jpg" alt="">
    <p class="img-text">Donnie Darko Review</p>
  </div>

  <div class="post box4">
    <img src="images/dk.jpg" alt="">
    <p class="img-text">Perfect Blue Review</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 55% 22.5% 22.5%;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 2.5px;
    height: 580px;
    max-width: 1700px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
  }

  .post {
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;       
    text-align: center;      
    overflow: hidden;        /*THIS IS THE OVERFLOW IN QUESTION*/   
  }

  .img-text {
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 16px;
  }

  .post img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: brightness(75%);
    transition: 1s;
  }
  
  .post img:hover {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);     
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05); 
    transform: scale(1.05); 
  }

  .box1 {
    grid-column: 1 / span 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  }

  .box2 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 2;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  }

  .box3 {
    grid-column: 2 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2 / span 1;
  }

  .box4 {
    grid-column: 3 / span 1;
    grid-row: 2 / span 1;
  }
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate?

Comment: @Paulie_D in the before and after photos it is shown how adding the overflow: hidden affects the overall look of the images and the grid. do u need any additional info?

Comment: We can't diagnose photos, that's why we need a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line of css code:

```
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
```

In the current configuration, when you set grid row to fr, the height of the entire container will depend on the height of the photo you put inside. You have two rows set to the same fr value and if you insert a smaller photo in one of them than in the other, it will be adjusted to the larger one, which will increase the container. As a quick fix, since you have height set as 580px, you can replace this line of code with:

```
grid-template-rows: 290px 290px;
```

The height of the container rows will be fixed and the photos will remain the same size.

Regards!